# Is asp:WizardStep a way to create long forms? (questionnaires)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wizard

I'm using mostly jQuery (with asp.net), however I need to create a questionnaire.

The user will have to answer (and type in) a lot of questions regarding the service that I'm going to provide for them. The answers will need to be validated (i.e. correct numbers, possible answers with ajax, check boxes, etc.) Therefore I chose to start using jQuery and possibly jQuery validator.

Now, because I don't want to scare off potential clients (and to make it easier) with a very long form, I decided that the best way would be to split the form into (possibly) several pages with next and previous buttons. I was thinking of simply storing it in the viewstate. 
Today I came across asp:wizardstep control, which seems to be doing just that.

The question of course is, is this the way to go? I don't want to spend hours or days trying to get this to work, only to find out that this is either not very practical, not very customizable, doesn't work well with jquery and perhaps is design only for short form (e.g. registration login pages)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to look at the `asp:Multiview` control which I’ve used a few times to split long forms up into pages. The problems you’ll have with jQuery will be the same whichever controls you use, generally getting the right client-side IDs.